# How to copy resources with scala + play + sbt

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am using sbt [0.13] to compile a play [2.2] project using scala [2.10.3]. I have .sql files and scala files used for database migrations. The directory structure looks like:

```
app
|-> db
     |-> migration
           |-> V1__init.scala
           |-> V2__newTable.sql
```

When I run compile from the play console (REPL), the scala file (V1__init.scala) is compiled to a .class and copied to the classes folder. But the .sql file is not moved.

I tried adding `unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++=  baseDirectory { dir => Seq(dir/"app/db/migration") ++ Seq(dir/"db/migration") }` but it did not copy the files. The whole block looks like:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.3",
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature"),   // enable feature warnings
    unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++=  baseDirectory { dir => Seq(dir/"app/db/migration") ++ Seq(dir/"db/migration") }
)
```

I also tried using `copyResources`, but couldn't get that to work. Described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTSettings

So does anyone know how I can copy the sql files to the classes folder?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I got `IO.copyDirectory(new java.io.File("app/db/migration"), new java.io.File("target/scala-2.10/classes/db/migration"), true)` to copy the files, but the destination is hard-coded and will change when I update scala

Comment: Have you considered using the [builtin support for database evolutions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3-SNAPSHOT/Evolutions)?

Comment: Yes I have, but it looks like evolutions does not support running arbitrary scala code, instead it needs .sql files

Comment: You can alternatively put the sql scripts into the conf dir, so it is automatically in the classpath.

Comment: @Schleichardt I had thought about this, but I don't think the conf dir is automatically compiled, which is needed so migration scripts can be written in scala or java. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.3",
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature"),   // enable feature warnings
    unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= scalaSource in Compile,
    excludeFilter in unmanagedResources in Compile := "*.scala" || "*.java"
  )
```

You can check easily the contents in the class folder with:

```
 sbt clean full-classpath && ls target/scala-2.10/classes/db/migration/
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost did exactly as I needed. I needed to add `".DS_Store"` to the exclusion list, so the full line looks like: `excludeFilter in unmanagedResources in Compile := "*.scala" || "*.java" || ".DS_Store"`